# Identity server getting custom in memory IdentityResources

Tags: identityserver4

after searching for two days to trying and identify where I am going wrong, I have accepted that I need some help to point me in the right direction.

I'm at the really early stages of working with Identity server, still simply using inMemory clients and scopes, just to get my head around what is happening and how it all links together.

I am trying to return a list of custom claims to my angular application from Identity server, but I am failing. I've tried extending `IProfileService`, which successfully adds the custom claim but it removes the other claims, that I defined in my `TestUser`

**With MyProfileService registered**

[image: With MyProfileService]

**Without MyProfileService registered**

[image: Without MyProfileService]

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        //services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

#if DEBUG
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
#endif

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

MyProfileService.cs

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    {
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // Issue custom claim
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("TenantId", "123456"));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Resources.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource> {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResource {
                Name = "role",
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
            },
            new IdentityResource
            {
                Name = "tenant.info",
                DisplayName = "Tenant Information",
                UserClaims = new List<string>
                {
                    "tenantid",
                    "subscriptionid"
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource> {
            new ApiResource("api1", "api1")
        };
    }
```

Users.cs

```
    public static List<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<TestUser> {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                Username = "scott",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("tenantid", "123456"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Scott xxxxx"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Scott"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "xxxxx"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "Scottxxxxx@email.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://alice.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, @"{ 'street_address': 'One Hacker Way', 'locality': 'Heidelberg', 'postal_code': 69118, 'country': 'Germany' }", IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json)
                }

            }
        };
    }
```

Clients.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client> {
            new Client {
                ClientId = "angular_spa",
                ClientName = "Angular 4 Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequirePkce = true,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200/admin/loggedin" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200/admin/loggedout" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200" },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            }
        };
    }
```

EDIT:
Additional failed solutions

1. Add default behaviour to MyProfileService (as suggested by the answer from Ruard van Elburg)

   ```
   public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
   {
   context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);
   context.IssuedClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("tenantId", "123456"));
   }
   ```

   **Result in client**: shows the tenantId but no other claims that I set on my TestUser

   ```
   profile:
   amr: ["pwd"]
   auth_time: 1553024858
   idp: "local"
   sid: "34f36d1c0056ad3d65d1671e339e73aa"
   sub: "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE"
   tenantId: "123456"
   __proto__: Object
   ```
2. Add subject.claims to issedClaims

   ```
   public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
   {
       context.IssuedClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("tenantId", "123456"));
       context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.Claims);
   }
   ```

   **Result in client**: shows the tenantId and name (which is referring to the username) but no claims that I set on my TestUser

   ```
   profile:
   amr: ["pwd"]
   auth_time: 1553025311
   idp: "local"
   name: "scott"
   sid: "831a89053b54f3df7c9ca1bca92e1e10"
   sub: "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE"
   tenantId: "123456"
   ```
3. Define custom identity resources ([resources docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=resources))

   I removed `MyProfileService` and added

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
   {
       var customProfile = new IdentityResource(
                               name: "custom.profile",
                               displayName: "Custom profile",
                               claimTypes: new[] {
                                   "name",
                                   "given_name",
                                   "family_name",
                                   "email",
                                   "email_verified",
                                   "website",
                                   "address",
                                   "status",
                                   "tenantid" });

   return new List<IdentityResource>
   {
       new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
       new IdentityResources.Profile(),
       customProfile
   };
   }
   ```

   **Result in client** I do not see all the claim types

   ```
   profile:
   amr: ["pwd"]
   auth_time: 1553026892
   family_name: "FamilyName"
   given_name: "Scott givenName"
   idp: "local"
   name: "Scott name"
   sid: "47ae7f9b5240742e2b2b94a739bed5fa"
   sub: "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE"
   website: "http://scott.com"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've removed default behaviour. So you'll need to restore that by adding the following line to your profile service (which is present in the DefaultProfileService):

```
context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);
```

But it is not necessary to implement your own IProfileService. In this case you can suffice by configuring the scope for the client:

```
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "tenant.info",
        "api1"
    },
```

And requesting the scope in the client:

```
options.Scope.Add("tenant.info");
```

This should be enough to include the tenantId claim.

Comment: I can't find where the `options.Scope.Add` function is in the oidc-client

Comment: Take a look at the [js sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/6_JavaScriptClient/src/JavaScriptClient/wwwroot/app.js#L21). I'd expect that there is a configuration file in your project as well. You can search for the string "openid profile api1"and change it to: "openid profile api1 tenant.info". Options.Scope is C# code. I didn't notice you have an angular client.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I have  an Angular client and I added "tenant.info" in the `allowedScopes` and added "tenant.info" to my `UserManagerSettings.scope` property. Now when I navigate to identity server I get `invalid_scope`

Comment: I've just reread my question, sorry for not adding that i'm using an Angular client, I guess it will make a difference?

Comment: Please note that by default the tokens are kept small. The id token will only contain the sub claim. In order to acquire additional information the UserInfo endpoint should be used. But you can set 'AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken' on the [client configuration](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html#token) to always include the claims.

Comment: I've added `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` when I decode the token I'm still only getting the same values that exist under profile